# Error while running services using Linuxbrew on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, osx-snow-leopard, homebrew

I am using Linux Ubuntu 16.04.
i need to install Homebrew for installing various applications like( kafka, redis, zookeeper, consul, Cassandra), but since i don’t use Mac, i have installed Linuxbrew instead.

When i install and start the applications using “brew service start redis” command, getting the following error message. For other applications also getting the same error message.

```
sh: 1: list: not found

Error: Failure while executing : load -w /home/localadmin/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.redis.plist
```

Please help how to resolve this error and install redis using Linuxbrew.

Comment: Honestly, I don't see why you would want to use a Homebrew-clone on Linux. Homebrew is a hack in itself to get Linux-style package management on MacOS. Just go with the developers instructions for the applications you want to install (since they're all built for, or very well supported, on Linux anyway).